# Count occurences in excel by first row in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel which is similar to that:

```
A B C A A
m n k m l
n m r s t
u i v   z
```

I want to count in how many coloumns with the header row X (for example, "A"), the string "m" appears.

I've tried to use some array functions but no success, I can't seem to be able to filter a the values based on the first row.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Select the table, **including the header row,** and run this small macro:

```
Sub MCounter()
    Dim TopRow As Range, r As Range
    Dim SomeCol As Range, K As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set TopRow = Intersect(Selection(1).EntireRow, Selection)
    K = 0
    For Each r In TopRow
        If r.Value = "A" Then
            Set SomeCol = Intersect(r(1).EntireColumn, Selection)
            If wf.CountIf(SomeCol, "m") > 0 Then
                K = K + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox K
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
 =IFERROR(IF(A1="A",MATCH("m",A2:A4,0),),"")
```

for each column and then sum the results.

Answer (score 0):

for each column do the array function:

`=SUM((A1="A")*(A2:A1000="m"))`

and then sum that row